# How to find smallest positive integer in data frame row

Tags: python, pandas

I have looked everywhere for this answer which must exist. I am trying to find the smallest positive integer per row in a data frame.

Imagine a dataframe

````
        'lat':[-120, -90, -100, -100],
        'long':[20, 21, 19, 18],
        'dist1':[2, 6, 8, 1],
        'dist2':[1,3,10,5]}```
````

The following function gives me the minimum value, but includes negatives. i.e. the df['lat'] column.

`df.min(axis = 1)`

Obviously, I could drop the lat column, or convert to string or something, but I will need it later. The lat column is the only column with negative values. I am trying to return a new column such as

`df['min_dist'] = [1,3,8,1]`

I hope this all makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter for just the `dist` columns and apply the minimum function :

```py
df.assign(min_dist = df.iloc[:, -2:].min(1))
Out[205]: 
   lat  long  dist1  dist2  min_dist
0 -120    20      2      1         1
1  -90    21      6      3         3
2 -100    19      8     10         8
3 -100    18      1      5         1
```

Comment: Thanks, Sammy. This works great, because I did have some non-int columns I need to skip over.

Answer (score 5):

In general you can use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to mark negative values as null and exclude them from `min` calculation:

```
df['min_dist'] = df.where(df > 0).min(1)
df
   lat  long  dist1  dist2  min_dist
0 -120    20      2      1       1.0
1  -90    21      6      3       3.0
2 -100    19      8     10       8.0
3 -100    18      1      5       1.0
```

Comment: Thank you Psidom!

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
df['min_dist'] = df[df > 0].min(1)
```